# How to publish MVC Web app via Amazon Elastic Beanstalk so that it will not delete any contents of the App_data directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, appdata

I am publishing web application on Amazon EC2 via Elastic Beanstalk from Visual studio 2017. I have given facility to the users to upload files on server and internally storing those files in App_Data folder. But while publishing every new build, its deleting all the files in App_Data folder that were previously uploaded by the users.

I also tried excluding App_Data folder from project and manually creating that folder from code. but its still deleting all files. Any Suggestion on this?

Do let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

You should not hold any data on your ElasticBeanstalk instances, you'll have issues when running multiple instances, and it's not very resilient.

One option is to [attach an Elastic File System (EFS) to your ElasticBeanstalk instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html), then treat this as a shared volume.

My preferred solution is to save the files to S3, either by [uploading from your application to the S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html), or using [generated pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) to upload directly from the user's browser.